# Is it possible to make an atomic transaction using web3.js only?

Tags: web3js, transactions

I am currently working on a project using web3.js that invloves making 2 transactions atomically. Is it possible to pass those 2 transactions in a single transaction object to make it atomic or is the only possible way to achieve this deploying a smart contract on the blockchain?

Comment: You can send the transactions sequentially from your client application. In this approach, you send the first transaction and wait for it to be confirmed on the blockchain before sending the second transaction. If the first transaction fails, you can prevent the second one from being sent.

Comment: what if the first transaction is successful but the second one fails? can i still revert the whole process?

Comment: If the second transaction fails, then I don't think that it's possible to revert the first transaction that is already being executed and changed some state as per its functionality. I think, it's only possible if you've coded the contract functions corresponding to the transactions by yourself or at least have read & write access of the state variables utilised by those transactions, then you can also add the corresponding rollback functions in the contract (or in the dependent contract) to revert the state changes depending on the failure of transaction(s).

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you used Safe Multisig, then you could use the **MultiSend** feature to submit multiple actions in one transaction batch. If one reverts, the whole transaction reverts.

> *Appeal to everyone to use multisigs to interact with contracts, **instead of EOAs**, as it is much safer and offers a bunch of additional features.*

Answer (score 0):

As a heuristic, you can only achieve atomicity if both transactions are wrapped in a single transaction.

As @tenbits suggested, a multisend might work, or else a purpose-built entry point that wraps both operations in a single contract function call. Be mindful of the context since the `msg.sender` will shift to the wrapper by default.

Hope it helps.